# Select Select Field Using SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table named Table1. I have the following fields:

```
Field Name               Type     Mode
name                     STRING   NULLABLE
items                    RECORD   REPEATED
items.properties         RECORD   REPEATED  
items.properties.name    STRING   NULLABLE  
items.properties.value   STRING   NULLABLE
```

Here's an example of what the table looks like:

```
name        items.properties.name        items.properties.value
---------------------------------------------------------------
ABC1        type                         1
            frequent                     1
---------------------------------------------------------------
ABC2        type                         2
            frequent                     1
---------------------------------------------------------------
ABC3        type                         2
            frequent                     2
---------------------------------------------------------------
ABC4        type                         1
            frequent                     2
```

Ultimately, I want to select the names and values of these items, but I'm consistently getting errors. Here's what I'm trying as a start:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT properties FROM UNNEST(items)) AS itemProp
FROM `Table1`
```

I've exhausted all my other ideas. But essentially, I just want to pull out all the values and names of the properties in individual rows so I can say `where items.properties.name = type AND items.properties.value = 1`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show me what you get if you change it to `...(SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: i've added what the table looks like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.* 
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t,
UNNEST(items) item, UNNEST(properties) property
WHERE property.name = 'type' 
AND property.value = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select prop.*
from t cross join
     (unnest(t.items)) item cross join
     (unnest(item.properties)) prop;
```

You have a strange data structure.  Only one repeated column is necessary.  I see no reason to repeat properties within items.